# Creation of CfnWebACL for rate based rule fails (AWS CDK WAF Regional)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-waf

I am trying to setup a rate based rule using AWS CDK (`@aws-cdk/aws-wafregional` v1.4.0).

This is my very simple JavaScript-setup:

```
const cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
const waf = require('@aws-cdk/aws-wafregional');


class TstStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const rule = new waf.CfnRateBasedRule(this, 'rule', {
            metricName: `rateRule`,
            name: 'rate-rule',
            rateKey: 'IP',
            rateLimit: 2010
        });

        const acl = new waf.CfnWebACL(this, 'acl', {
            defaultAction: { type: 'ALLOW' },
            metricName: 'rateAcl',
            name: 'rate-acl',
            rules: [{
                action: { type: 'BLOCK' },
                priority: 1,
                ruleId: rule.ref
            }]
        });
    }
}

module.exports = { TstStack }
```

To create the rule is no problem. But the stack creation fails on the Web ACL. The error message is:

```
The referenced item does not exist. (Service: AWSWAFRegional; Status Code: 400; Error Code: WAFNonexistentItemException
```

What am I missing here, why is it not possible to create the CfnWebACL-object?

For reference, the complete output:

```
3/4 | 9:49:31 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::WAFRegional::WebACL        | acl The referenced item does not exist. (Service: AWSWAFRegional; Status Code: 400; Error Code: WAFNonexistentItemException; Request ID: e4d897ef-c138-11e9-bf23-fb4702c5a89a)
    new TstStack (/app/infrastructure/apps/tst/lib/tst-stack.js:16:21)
    \_ Object.<anonymous> (/app/infrastructure/apps/tst/bin/tst.js:9:1)
    \_ Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    \_ Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    \_ Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    \_ tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    \_ Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    \_ Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    \_ startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    \_ bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: I'm seeing similar issue with CF template today https://gist.github.com/codeasone/5faab795c22f77827f91979dd1e5c084

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed for `terraform` https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/4978 but "Type" is an unsupported property in CF so a similar remedy does not appear to be available.

Answer (score 3):

This aggravated me for a while also. I finally saw the following in the CloudFormation documentation for the [rate-rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafregional-ratebasedrule.html):

> Note you can only create rate-based rules using a CloudFormation template. To add the rate-based rules created through CloudFormation to a web ACL, use the AWS WAF console, API, or command line interface (CLI). For more information, see [UpdateWebACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_regional_UpdateWebACL.html).

Basically, you can create the rule, but you can't associate it with an ACL through AWS CloudFormation.

Comment: is this still true ?